# Cannot add new tables via Entity Framework

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework, model

I'm encountering a very odd problem. Since 2 days I cannot add new tables from my db in the model.
They appear in the list of addable tables, no error are shown at the validation but then, they don't appear in the Entity lists, and they still appear in the "addable" part of the menu.
The problem appears in

We've tried from different computeurs, so it's not a problem of my specific visual studio.
We've tried with other dbs, and the problem doesn't affect them. It affects boths of my prod and developpment dbs though.
We've tried with the exact same credentials to log to the db (not window authentication as we usually do), and the problem remains, so it's not a problem of rights.

We're a bit out of ideas right now :/

Does someone have an idea what it could be?

Thanks

Comment: add some code please...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Ok, we've found where it came from.

The table we wanted to add had no PK, and then when we tested we created mock tables without PK.

Once we add a PK the import goes well =)

Answer (score 0):

If you're using a Code First approach then Entity Framework will build the table for you. It looks like you are not using Code First, so you will have create the table in the database. I assume you're using an Entity Data Model (.edmx)? If so, you will create your table in the database, then update your data model (.edmx). If you have not yet created your .edmx file, you need to do that - the .edmx file will contain all your CRUD operations.

What I'm confused about is I'd imagine your code would throw an error if the table did not exist (i.e. if the table represented by your data model didn't map to an actual table in the database, because it doesn't exist). So, the question is, does your table already exist? If it does, then step through the code line by line to find out why your records aren't being saved. If it doesn't exist, then add the table via SQL Server Management Studio (or similar), then open your .edmx file, right click on the layout that comes up, click "Update Model from database".